# How to share a variable that is set inside a block

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have a method that does the following (using open-uri)

```
def convert_html(remote_url)
  open(remote_url) do |file|
    # After some file manipulation, I do an assignment
    rendered_html = find_html_to_render
  end
  # How can I access rendered_html here??
end
```

I would like to know how I can access `rendered_html` once the IO operations with `open` have finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the variable outside of the block.

```
def convert_html(remote_url)
  rendered_html = nil
  open(remote_url) do |file|
    # After some file manipulation, I do an assignment
    rendered_html = find_html_to_render
  end
  ...
end
```